# Is it possible to replace an image in a web page based on the user's geolocation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I've been looking hard on Google for some information on this but I haven't come up with anything. Anyhow, what I want to do is change the image source (either for img tag or background-image css property) based on the users location.

Looking to leverage of the HTML5 Geolocation feature and then run a conditional statement that compares their location to a number of set locations (as variables). The function finds the set location that the user is closest to and then replaces the image based on the result. I am thinking this could be done with latLong - hopefully just comparing numbers with operator functions.

I'm fairly sure this would be done with Jquery/Javascript - injecting the necessary HTML/CSS into the page upon the results of the function. Just still wrapping my head around it.

Has anyone done or seen anything like this before so I can look at how the code is structured so I could verify my assumptions? JS is not my biggest strength and any advice or help would be most helpful.

Comment: At a high level you'd basically decompose this into smaller pieces of functionality. Pieces might include: 1) Using HTML5 geolocation in general, how to get a value out of that. 2) Selecting an item from a known array of items based on conditional logic. 3) How to update the page with an image URL.  Each of these independently is something you can look up on Google, attempt, test, tinker with, etc. It's unlikely that you'll find a tutorial that does *exactly* what you're trying to do, but each individual piece of functionality should be findable and then you simply piece them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah it's definitely possible. Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j0m8z2wj/1):

```
var body = document.body;

function locate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            if(position.coords.latitude > 50 && position.coords.longitude > 15) {
                body.innerHTML = 'You might be in Europe';
                console.log('You might be in Europe');
            } else {
                body.innerHTML = 'You are probably not in Europe';
                console.log('You are probably not in Europe');                                          
            }
        });
    } else {
        console.log(false);
    }
};

locate();
```

*When you run the example above, make sure you click "allow" when it asks for your location, and give it a second to find you.*

This is just a cheesy example, but as you can see, it roughly estimates your location based on latitude and longitude and provides output in the form of a statement (however, you could easy make this the URL of an image, etc.)

Here are some resources for you to delve into the API:

- [Dive Into HTML5 Geolocation](http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html)
- [MDN (how to use the geolocation object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation)

My suggestion to you is to just start Googling.  There are numerous implementations of this.

## EDIT

One more thing... To really understand the API, I suggest using the console to no end. For example, you can do this:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    console.log(position);
});
```

Then open your console in whatever browser you are using, and check out the object.

[image: console log of geolocation object]

Comment: Thanks Josh, that really helped out a great deal. I have used Geolocation before in this project http://thebeachschool.eq.edu.au/freshwater-app/locator.html so I have played with the API in PhoneGap before (used console alot). I played with your code in JS Fiddle for my particular location in QLD, Australia. Funny thing is, the Geolocation was waaay off. It was pegging me at approx 38.79,22.57 (somewhere in Greece) when I'm actually at -28,153. I will work with it some more and have the JS apply classes to HTML element depending on location result.

Comment: @RyanCoolwebs, glad it worked for you. Cool site by the way. Don't forget to hit the checkmark button if this is the accepted answer. Also, I'd venture to guess that geolocation itself wasn't off. It's just software. It relies on accurate hardware to get a good signal. If the hardware isn't getting a proper signal, geolocation can't interpret it correctly.

Comment: I'm using a real messed up computer at work right now. It's struggling with just brackets and having a few browsers open right now. I will check on my laptop. Interestingly though, I did location test on google maps and also that old website I did and they worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is doable using something like Google's Geocode API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/) or the HTML5 geolocation functionality (http://diveintohtml5.info/geolocation.html)

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(data) {
  // data.coords.latitude & data.coords.longitude
});
```